# Using resources as input in maven

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception

I want to use a docx file from my project, I have a class called inputDoc.java in com.src.myPackage. Also the docx file is in the same package. Now I used the following line to get the input

```
InputStream in = GenerateController.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("/DocxProjectWithVelocity.docx");
```

I am getting file not found exception in my maven project. But it works with ordinary java class with main method.

I am newer to maven, any assistance in this would be great. Thanks in advance....

[image]

Comment: If the file is in the same package as the calling class, just the file name **without** the `/` should work fine. With the `/`, you are saying the file is at the root of the classpath

Comment: I used that too as ("DocxProjectWithVelocity.docx");.... It refers to the tomcat bin folder..

Comment: If you have the resource file right under `src/main/resources` (or any other buildpath for that matter), `GenerateController.class.getResourceAsStream("/DocxProjectWithVelocity.docx");` should suffice. If it's under a package though, say, `docs` within the `src/main/resources` buildpath or any other buildpath, you can access it like `GenerateController.class.getResourceAsStream("/docs/DocxProjectWithVelocity.docx");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've put the file under the same package: `com/src/myPackage` (under of the `main` buildpaths), you can access the file like:

```
GenerateController.class.
  getResourceAsStream("/com/src/myPackage/DocxProjectWithVelocity.doc‌​x")
```

If you instead put it right under one of the `main` buildpaths, like, say, under: `src/main/resources`, you can access it like the way you did:

```
GenerateController.class.getResourceAsStream("/DocxProjectWithVelocity.doc‌​x")
```

Comment: I tried in both ways and got the same error as follows,   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /DocxProjectWithVelocity1.docx (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)

Comment: Is there anything I need to mention anywhere?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the folder structure of your project showing the relevant files?

Comment: ss add3ed in question

Comment: So the resource file is right under `src/main/resources` then. After building the project, can you check the `target` folder to see if the `docx` file is there right under the `classes` folder? If so, you should be able to access it this way: `GenerateController.class.getResourceAsStream("/DocxProjectWithVelocity.doc‌​x")`.

Comment: Then you should be able to access it this way: `GenerateController.class.getResourceAsStream("/DocxProjectWithVelocity.doc‌​x")‌`. You can confirm this behavior by creating a simple maven project with minimal setup - just the class and the resource.

Comment: In my project it says file not found error. Any ideas

Comment: May I try with following------------ File file = new File("DocxProjectWithVelocity.doc‌​x")

Comment: @Mary.Hansen Nope, won't work. Just create a simple maven project and try what I suggested. If it works, which I'm sure will, compare that with this setup and try to resolve.